# How play video without stop other audio tracks?

Tags: android, audio, video

When I playing video in my application, other audio stop playing. Because my video has no sound, so I don't want to stop other audio.
I have tried to mute my video by set volume to 0 but it doesn't help

```
setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.setVolume(0f, 0f);
    }
});
```

Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated

Comment: I'm not a pro, but I'm trying to help. I think you need to release your audio focus when your video start to play. Take a look: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones.html#audio-focus

Comment: @Alan thank you so much, now I understand why this happened

Comment: Should I add it as an answer? I think not, btw.

Comment: @Alan I find that we can not release the audio focus but the link that you give is really helpful, you can share it as the answer